How do I convert BGRA8888 CameraImage to Image with Flutter on iOS?
I want to take a picture with the camera package which gives me a CameraImage and convert it to Image format used by the image package (so I can rotate, manipulate it etc).
Image.decodeBytes doesn't work and just returns null.

This code successfully converts the image on iOS:
const IOS_BYTES_OFFSET = 28;

static Image _convertBGRA8888ToImage(CameraImage cameraImage) {
  final plane = cameraImage.planes[0];

  return Image.fromBytes(
    width: cameraImage.width,
    height: cameraImage.height,
    bytes: plane.bytes.buffer,
    rowStride: plane.bytesPerRow,
    bytesOffset: IOS_BYTES_OFFSET,
    order: ChannelOrder.bgra,
  );
}

For reference, the answer above appears on another partially related question as an unaccepted answer but is too hard to find as the question wasn't directly asking for this: How to convert camera image to image?
